# Trouble Binding Jar Library In Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

While Binding my jar files I keep getting this error in multiple classes:

```
Error CS0534: 'path’ does not implement inherited abstract memberAndroid.OS.AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params 
Java.Lang.Object[])' (CS0534)
```

Along with a few other errors such as:

```
 ‘package’.Get(int)' hides inherited abstract member `Java.Util.AbstractList.Get(int)' (CS0533)

`package’: member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type (CS0542)
```

Could this be an issue with the jars or the namespaces for native android? Is there a way to fix these errors? Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I have a general guide that might help in some areas:

https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

I believe your current scenario can be fixed via the following:

Ideally you need to change the `managedType` to `Java.Lang.Object`.

```
<!-- There are also some methods that need to have their generic _parameter_ types simplified to `java.lang.Object`.
         Possible error message: Error CS0115: `SomeMethod(..., T, ...)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override (CS0115)
         Possible error message: Error CS0535: `SomeClass' does not implement interface member `SomeMethod(..., Java.Lang.Object,...)' (CS0535)
         Possible error message: Error CS0534: `SomeClass' does not implement inherited abstract member `SomeMethod(..., Java.Lang.Object,...)' (CS0534) -->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.socialize.api']/class[@name='SocializeApi.AsyncAuthenicator']/method[@name='doInBackground' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.socialize.api.SocializeRequest']]/parameter[1]" name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.socialize.api']/class[@name='SocializeApi.AsyncGetter']/method[@name='doInBackground' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.socialize.api.SocializeRequest']]/parameter[1]" name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.socialize.api']/class[@name='SocializeApi.AsyncPutter']/method[@name='doInBackground' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.socialize.api.SocializeRequest']]/parameter[1]" name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/brendanzagaeski/9607158#file-metadata-xml-L74-L76

For your other issue, you can remove the node via `<remove-node>`

You can do the following:

```
<!-- The bindings generator does not currently handle cases where a subclass provides an abstract override for an
     abstract method. From what I've seen, there is no need to keep abstract overrides of abstract methods in the
     binding, so we can remove them.
     Error message: Error CS0533: `SomeMethodName' hides inherited abstract member `SomeMethodName' (CS0533) -->
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.socialize.entity']/class[@name='SocializeActionFactory']/method[@name='postFromJSON' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='org.json.JSONObject'] and parameter[2][@type='T']]" />
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.socialize.entity']/class[@name='SocializeActionFactory']/method[@name='postToJSON' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='T'] and parameter[2][@type='org.json.JSONObject']]" />
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/brendanzagaeski/9607158#file-metadata-xml-L63-L68

**Please note that you will need to tweak these examples to your package and class names.**

Comment: Thanks fir the feedback! I implemented these into my project meta data and it built with no errors. Now when I add a reference to the library in my Droid project and try to build the application I am faced with a new error: 

mandroiderror XA0000: Invalid create-package command: -v --nosign --sdk-dir

any ideas on what this error means? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for that guide! Xamarin bindings are frustrating and that documentation is excellent!