# Issues with binding Jar In Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

As I mentioned in this post: [Trouble Binding Jar Library In Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489333/trouble-binding-jar-library-in-xamarin)

I am having issues with binding Jar librarys. Once I imported the Jars and compiled the project I encounered some errors such as:

```
Error CS0534: 'path’ does not implement inherited abstract memberAndroid.OS.AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params 
Java.Lang.Object[])' (CS0534)
```

I fixed these issues by removing the node with:

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.socialize.entity']/class[@name='SocializeActionFactory']/method[@name='postFromJSON' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='org.json.JSONObject'] and parameter[2][@type='T']]" />
```

Now, when I add a reference to the library in my Android Project and build the application I get this error:

```
mandroiderror XA0000: Invalid create-package command: -v --nosign --sdk-dir
```

How can I fix this issue? Thank you for the help in advance!

Edit:

Application output:

```
Project "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/asdasdadsasdasd.Droid.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target(s)):

Target _BuildSdkCache:
Skipping target "_BuildSdkCache" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target PrepareForBuild:
    Configuration: Debug Platform: AnyCPU

Target _GenerateAndroidAssetsDir:
No output files were specified for target _GenerateAndroidAssetsDir, skipping.

Target _ResolveMonoAndroidSdks:
    MonoAndroid Tools: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mandroid/
    MonoAndroid Binaries: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/bin/
    Android Platform API level: 23
    TargetFrameworkVersion: v6.0
    Android NDK: /Users/THiNC/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10e/
    Android SDK: /Users/THiNC/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/
    Android SDK Build Tools: /Users/THiNC/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.1/
    Java SDK: /usr/

Target _ValidateAndroidPackageProperties:
      PackageName: thinc.technology.asdasdadsasdasd

Target _ResolveLibraryProjectImports:
Skipping target "_ResolveLibraryProjectImports" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _BuildLibraryImportsCache:
Skipping target "_BuildLibraryImportsCache" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _BuildAdditionalResourcesCache:
Skipping target "_BuildAdditionalResourcesCache" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _CreateAdditionalResourceCache:
Skipping target "_CreateAdditionalResourceCache" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _GenerateAndroidResourceDir:
Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidResourceDir" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _UpdateAndroidResgen:
Skipping target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _GenerateJavaDesignerForComponent:
No input files were specified for target _GenerateJavaDesignerForComponent, skipping.

Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.

Target _CoreXamlG:
No input files were specified for target _CoreXamlG, skipping.

Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _CreateIntermediateAssembliesDir:
Skipping target "_CreateIntermediateAssembliesDir" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _CopyConfigFiles:
No output files were specified for target _CopyConfigFiles, skipping.

Target _CopyIntermediateAssemblies:
Skipping target "_CopyIntermediateAssemblies" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _ConvertPdbFiles:
No output files were specified for target _ConvertPdbFiles, skipping.

Target _CopyMdbFiles:
Skipping target "_CopyMdbFiles" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _StripEmbeddedLibraries:
Skipping target "_StripEmbeddedLibraries" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _GenerateJavaStubs:
Skipping target "_GenerateJavaStubs" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _AddStaticResources:
Skipping target "_AddStaticResources" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _GeneratePackageManagerJava:
Skipping target "_GeneratePackageManagerJava" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _CreateBaseApk:
Skipping target "_CreateBaseApk" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _CompileJava:
Skipping target "_CompileJava" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _CompileToDalvik:
Skipping target "_CompileToDalvik" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _BuildApkFastDev:
Skipping target "_BuildApkFastDev" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _Mandroid:
    :  mandroiderror XA0000: Invalid create-package command: -v --nosign --sdk-     dir="/Users/THiNC/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/" --     builddir="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/android" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v6.0" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v5.1" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v5.0" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.4.87" --framework-        dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.4" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.3" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.2" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.1" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.0.3" --framework-     dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v2.3" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/" -     S="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/res/" --package="thinc.technology.     asdasdadsasdasd" --     input="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/android/bin/resources_and_assemblies" --       output="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/android/bin/thinc.technology.asdasdadsasdasd      .apk"   --nolink --abi="arm64-v8a;armeabi;armeabi-v7a;x86;x86_64" --java-sdk-dir="/usr/" --debug --     manifest-template="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml" --sdk-       platform="23" -A="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/assets/" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Project      s/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/armeabi/libonyx-        java-jni.so,armeabi" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/      library_project_imports/jni/armeabi/libopencv_java.so,armeabi" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/      Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/armeabi-v7a/libonyx-java-jni.     so,armeabi-v7a" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/libra      ry_project_imports/jni/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so,armeabi-v7a" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasda      sd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/mips/libonyx-java-jni.so" -nf="/U      sers/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/      mips/libopencv_java.so" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/on      yx/library_project_imports/jni/x86/libonyx-java-jni.so,x86" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Dro      id/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/x86/libopencv_java.so,x86"       "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/bin/Debug/asdasdadsasdasd.Droid.dll"       "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/System.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/System.Xml.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v6.0/Mono.Android.dll"       "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.21.0.3.      0/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll"         "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.3.5.6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Forms.       Platform.Android.dll" "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.3.5.      6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/FormsViewGroup.dll" "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.Forms.1      .3.5.6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll"         "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.3.5.6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Forms.       Xaml.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/System.Core.      dll" "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/onyx/bin/Debug/onyx.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.     framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/mscorlib.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.      framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll"        "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Collections      .dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.       ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-        frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.       framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.ComponentModel.dll"        "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Diagnostics      .Contracts.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.      0/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-        frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.        framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll"       "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Dynamic.     Runtime.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.     0/Facades/System.Globalization.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-        frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.IO.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-     frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Linq.Expressions.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.     framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Linq.Parallel.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Linq.        Queryable.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.       0/Facades/System.Linq.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.       0/Facades/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-       frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Net.Primitives.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.       framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Net.Requests.dll"      "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.ObjectModel      .dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.       Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-      frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.      framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Reflection.Emit.dll"       "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Reflection.      Extensions.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.      0/Facades/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-        frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Reflection.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.       framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.     Extensions.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.      0/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.     framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll"       "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.     Numerics.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.        0/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-       frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono      .framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll"        "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.     dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.        Security.Principal.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.      0/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Http.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-        frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.      framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Security.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Text.        Encoding.Extensions.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.     0/Facades/System.Text.Encoding.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-        frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.      framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll"      "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Threading.       Tasks.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.      Threading.Timer.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.     0/Facades/System.Threading.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-        frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.     framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Xml.XDocument.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Xml.     XmlSerializer.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.       0/mscorlib.dll" "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.3.5.        6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll" "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.     Forms.1.3.5.6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/FormsViewGroup.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild      -frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.dll" --profiler="log"
        Task "Mandroid" execution -- FAILED
        Done building target "_Mandroid" in project         "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/asdasdadsasdasd.Droid.csproj".-- FAILED

    Done building project "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/asdasdadsasdasd.Droid.csproj".-- FAILED

    Build FAILED.
    Errors:

    /Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/asdasdadsasdasd.Droid.csproj (SignAndroidPackage) ->
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (     _Mandroid target) ->

        :  mandroiderror XA0000: Invalid create-package command: -v --nosign --sdk-     dir="/Users/THiNC/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/" --     builddir="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/android" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v6.0" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v5.1" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v5.0" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.4.87" --framework-        dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.4" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.3" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.2" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.1" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v4.0.3" --framework-     dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v2.3" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0" --framework-       dir="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/" -     S="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/res/" --package="thinc.technology.     asdasdadsasdasd" --     input="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/android/bin/resources_and_assemblies" --       output="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/android/bin/thinc.technology.     asdasdadsasdasd.apk"   --nolink --abi="arm64-v8a;armeabi;armeabi-v7a;x86;x86_64" --java-sdk-        dir="/usr/" --debug --manifest-     template="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml" --sdk-        platform="23" -A="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/assets/" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Pro      jects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/armeabi/li      bonyx-java-jni.so,armeabi" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projec      ts__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/armeabi/libopencv_java.so,armeabi" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/as      dasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/armeabi-        v7a/libonyx-java-jni.so,armeabi-v7a" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__libr      ary_projects__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so,armeabi-v7a" -nf="/Users      /THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/      mips/libonyx-java-jni.so" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_project      s__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/mips/libopencv_java.so" -nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdas      d/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/library_project_imports/jni/x86/libonyx-java-jni.so,x86" -      nf="/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/obj/Debug/__library_projects__/onyx/library_project_im      ports/jni/x86/libopencv_java.so,x86"        "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/Droid/bin/Debug/asdasdadsasdasd.Droid.dll"       "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/System.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/System.Xml.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v6.0/Mono.Android.dll"       "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.21.0.3.      0/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll"         "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.3.5.6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.     Forms.Platform.Android.dll" "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.3.5.        6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/FormsViewGroup.dll" "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.     Forms.1.3.5.6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll"      "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.3.5.6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.     Forms.Xaml.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/System      .Core.dll" "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/onyx/bin/Debug/onyx.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.       framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/mscorlib.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.      framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll"        "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.     Collections.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.     0/Facades/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-       frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll"      "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.     ComponentModel.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.      0/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-        frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.        framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.     Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1      .0/Facades/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-     frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Globalization.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.        framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.IO.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono      .framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Linq.Expressions.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Linq.        Parallel.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.        0/Facades/System.Linq.Queryable.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-       frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Linq.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.     framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll"        "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Net.     Primitives.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.      0/Facades/System.Net.Requests.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-     frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.ObjectModel.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.      framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.      dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.        Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-       frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Reflection.Emit.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.      framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.     Reflection.Primitives.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-     frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Reflection.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.       framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime      .Extensions.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.     0/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.     framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll"       "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime      .Numerics.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.       0/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-       frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll"        "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime      .Serialization.Xml.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.      0/Facades/System.Runtime.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-      frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Security.Principal.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.       framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Http.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.     ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-       frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Security.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.        framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll"      "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Text.        Encoding.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.        0/Facades/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-      frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.     framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.dll"       "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.     Threading.Timer.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.     0/Facades/System.Threading.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-        frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.     framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Xml.XDocument.dll"         "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Xml.     XmlSerializer.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.       0/mscorlib.dll" "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.3.5.        6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll" "/Users/THiNC/Projects/asdasdadsasdasd/packages/Xamarin      .Forms.1.3.5.6335/lib/MonoAndroid10/FormsViewGroup.dll" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.      framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Runtime.dll" --profiler="log"

         0 Warning(s)
         1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:01.3374720

    Package creation failed.
```

Xamarin Studio Version:

```
 === Xamarin Studio Community ===

Version 5.10.3 (build 51)
Installation UUID: de70b209-1d80-47f9-9312-9ba90429c30b
Runtime:
    Mono 4.2.3 (explicit/832de4b)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 402030004

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Not Installed

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 7.2.1 (9548.1)
Build 7C1002

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 9.6.1.9 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Hash: 5f11db8
Branch: master
Build date: 2016-03-25 21:26:55-0400

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 6.0.3.5 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/Eric/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.4   (API level 19)
        6.0   (API level 23)

SDK Tools Version: 25.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 23.1
SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.1

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Xamarin Android Player ===

Not Installed

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Not Installed

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 510030051
Git revision: f3c0d982165f785772d125f02668370d929014fb
Build date: 2016-03-24 18:51:31-04
Xamarin addins: ee5cfd3ecb6b20de47c1d25efb9a9abc101e8ce7
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle6-c6sr3

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.11.3
Darwin Erics-iMac.local 15.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0
    Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015
    root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Can you attach your version information and your diagnostic build output?

In Xamarin Studio, version information can be obtained by navigating to: Xamarin Studio -> About Xamarin Studio -> Show Details -> Copy Information button (on Mac) or Help -> About -> Show Details -> Copy Information button (on Windows)

In Visual Studio, version information can be copied from: Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio -> Copy Info button

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

Comment: I attached the requested info in the post!

Comment: Can you also attach the output(b.txt) of the following? In Terminal.app run the following:

`export __XA_LOG_ERRORS__=icanhaz
xbuild /v:diag /t:SignAndroidPackage YourProject.csproj > b.txt`

Comment: XBuild Engine Version 12.0
Mono, Version 4.2.3.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors
Loading default tasks for ToolsVersion: 4.0 from /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.3/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.tasks
MSBUILD: error MSBUILD0000: Project file 'project.Droid.csproj' not found.

Comment: Are you in the correct directory? Ensure there is a valid `.csproj` which xbuild will run.

Comment: Could you clarify which directory you're referring to? Our .csproj is located at the root of our Droid directory:

 /Users/THiNC/Projects/Bindproject/Droid/Bindproject.Droid.csproj 

Does it need to be elsewhere? Or is there a build path we need to check? Thanks!

Comment: `xbuild` should be able to run anywhere if it's in your respective path. `xbuild` however needs a valid .csproj via a path in the terminal. Thus you should specify the complete path and the .csproj via the example given above. If you are not in the current directory, then change to the directory and run it. Otherwise just copy the path as well.

Comment: gotcha! do i need to replace the ' v:diag' with anything?

Comment: Nope. `/v:diag` is merely saying "Set the Verbosity to Diagnostic". This is simply shorthand for the complete parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx